# Encoded HTML stored under XML

Tags: android, html

Recently while making a feed analyzer app in android I have faced a XML file where HTML code is stored inside it and is encoded like these...

```
.......&lt;a href=&quot;http://xxx.xxx/movie/Earth_1991&quot;&gt;&lt;img style=&quot;float:left&quot; src=&quot;http://xxx.xxx/attachments/Earth_1991/poster_med.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;Earth (1991) -  xxx-xxx&quot; /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;  &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102536/&quot;&gt;http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102536/&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;IMDB Rating: 7.8/10&lt;br /&gt;......
```

**WHAT KIND OF ENCODING TECHNIQUE IS THIS?
AND
HOW I CAN CHANGE IT TO NORMAL HTML STRING?**

Comment: That is a way to express special chars (including HTML reserved characters) in HTML via entities. See: http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html and http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called HTML entities. You can encode and decode them here: http://www.web2generators.com/html/entities

Answer (score 1):

That is *the* way to express special chars (including HTML reserved characters) in HTML via **HTML entities**.

The way to "*undo*" this encoding depends on the method you used to encode the HTML. For instance in PHP you have the couple 
`htmlentities()` to encode and `html_entity_decode()` to reverse the process.

#### Android Example

If you have HTML inside, for instance, `String.xml` as follows:

```
<resources>
    <string name="hello">&lt;div&gt;</string>
</resources>
```

In your code: `getResources().getString(R.string.hello);` will evaluate to `<div>`. You can then use it as follows:

```
TextView hello = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.hello );
hello.setText( Html.fromHtml( getString ( R.string.hello ) ) );
```

Have a look [here](http://utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html) and [here](http://w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp).

Comment: The XML I am talking about was not a resource string. Its a web feed which am fetching from a site and then trying to display its contents. There was a <description> element under which the encoded HTML was stored. Any way, now I know the encoding does not matter because if it is passed in a WebView widget, the html content automatically decoded and displayed including any picture inside it. But I did not knew the getString method can be used to decode encoded html. Thanks for the information.